# "Vorbereiten" and its past participle form

Tags: perfect-tense

Is there a particular grammatical rule for the form of the past participle of *vorbereiten*?
I mean, *vorbereiten* is a separable verb, so it would be sensible to have, let's say, "Er hat vorgebereitet", but the correct form is "Er hat vorbereitet". 
Am I missing something?

Let's take two separable verbs, **durch**führen and **vor**bereiten:

- In the first case, we have, e.g., "Sie hat Aufträge **durch**geführt".
- In the second case, we have, e.g., "Sie hat Besprechungen **vor**bereitet".

Could you tell me why there's no *ge* in the second case?

Comment: You are missing that the past participle of *bereiten* is *bereitet*.

Comment: Please see my edit.

Comment: Also, the choice of verb to be compaired with "durchführen" is not very good, since it dan be either "durchführt" or "durchgeführt" in perfect depending on the meaning, "carried out/effected" or "lead throught"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "Perfekt" is built as followed:

"Hilfsverb" + Nomen + Partizip 2

So we have to focus on the "Partizip 2"
In German normally the "Partizip 2" is built as followed:

Weak Verbs/Mixed Verbs:

"ge" + Verbstamm + "t"/"et"/"en" ...

Strong Verbs:

"ge" + Perfektstamm + "en"

There are some verbs which build the "Partizip 2" without the "ge":

- die untrennbaren Verben mit den Präfixen er-, ver-, zer-, be-, ge-, ent-, emp-, hinter-
- Verben auf -ieren
- trennbare Verben, die mit einem Verb aus Punkt 1&2 gebildet wurden
- die Verben mit den Präfixen über-, unter-, um-, durch-, wider-, wenn sie unbetont und untrennbar sind

Your verb "vorbereiten" is included in the 3rd Point, **its separable, but mixed with "be"** and that's the reason why you don't write it with "ge". Other examples for this rule would be:

- abbezahlt
- überreagiert

Comment: Danke für die Erklärung!

Comment: Keine Ursache, immer wieder gerne.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you refer to a rule that the past participle of a separable verb *prefix+base* is *prefix+participle of base* (e.g. *umhören* -> *umgehört*), while in the Inseparable case the *ge-* of the participle of the base is dropped (e.g. *verhören* -> *verhört*). In this case however, the participle of *bereiten* has no *ge-* to begin with, it is *bereitet*. So the participle *vorbereitet* still follows that rule if it is properly formulated.

As to why the participle of *bereiten* is not * *gebereitet*, I assume that it is treated as an insepearable verb itself, even though I think that this is etymologically not fully correct.

Comment: "while in the *in*separable case", right?

Yes, then the question is why the particle of bereiten is not "gebereitet".
Ok, so it is a peculiarity of "bereiten". Thank you!

Comment: @Marco Participle of "bereiten" is not "gebereiten" because it is not separable like any other verb with prefix "be-". You can see a list of unseparable prefixes [on this page](https://deutsch.lingolia.com/de/grammatik/verben/trennbare) (as an example).

Comment: Now I understand, I hope. Danke!